# iOS: How to Get the Device Current Language Setting?

Tags: ios, locale, local, setting

There are some features within my application that are supposed to be based on the language settings of the device where it's running.

I want to get the actual language and not some country settings. Foe example, if the language is English, I don't care if it's US, UK, Australia, etc...

I'm familiar with the `NSLocale` object, but it seems to relate to the `Region Format` setting and not to the **Language** setting (see screen shot below) so when I try to retrieve the language out of it using `[locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:[locale localeIdentifier]` I get things like `English (United States)` instead of `English`; also, I think that what I need is the **Language** data and not the **Region Format** (am I right?).

Can anyone direct me to how to retrieve the language setting?

[image]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

User preferred languages are stored can be retrieved from locale as array and current language identifier is the first object in that array:

```
NSString *currentLanguage = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

If you want language in more readable form then use `displayNameForKey:value:` method of NSLocale:

```
NSString *langID = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *lang = [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode value:langID];
```

Comment: what is 's' parameter at the end? Should it be langID?

Comment: @Flink, langID indeed. thank your for comment, I'll edit the answer. It'sweird that error remained unspotted for so long :)

Comment: ***Warning: in iOS 9***, the return value of the `NSLocale preferredLanguages` changed. If before you have been getting "en" only, in iOS 9 you will get "en-US" or "en-JP", etc. Reference: https://happyteamlabs.com/blog/nslocale-preferredlanguages-changes-in-ios-9/

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray* arrayLanguages = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
NSString* currentLanguage = [arrayLanguages objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 3):

Getting language and region in `Swift`:

```
    LF.log("language", NSLocale.preferredLanguages())
    LF.log("locale", NSBundle.mainBundle().preferredLocalizations)
```

In my case I'm getting:

```
language: '(
    "zh-Hans"
)'
locale: '(
    en
)'
```

Comment: `NSBundle.mainBundle().preferredLocalizations` does not give current device language.The gives the language that you have given in CFBundleDevelopmentRegion of info.plist if CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations is true in info.plist then first item of CFBundleLocalizations in info.plist is returned

Answer (score 3):

In **Swift 4**:

```
let currentLanguage = Locale.current.languageCode
```

It will give you just the language code, no country code.

Answer (score 2):

Swift:

```
let language = NSBundle.mainBundle().preferredLocalizations[0] as NSString
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is a wrong answer. If you set your system language to French and your "Language and Region" is set to the US, you'll get "en" instead of "fr", whilst the question was asking about language.

Comment: `NSBundle.mainBundle().preferredLocalizations` does not give current device language.The gives the language that you have given in CFBundleDevelopmentRegion of info.plist if CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations is true in info.plist then first item of CFBundleLocalizations in info.plist is returned

Answer (score 2):

Working solution:

```
    let language = NSLocale.preferredLanguages()[0]
    let languageDic = NSLocale.componentsFromLocaleIdentifier(language) as NSDictionary
    //let countryCode = languageDic.objectForKey("kCFLocaleCountryCodeKey")
    let languageCode = languageDic.objectForKey("kCFLocaleLanguageCodeKey") as! String
    print(languageCode)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the solution in XCode's helper document, it wrote:

Getting the Current Language

To get the language that the app is using from the main application bundle, use the preferredLocalizations method in the NSBundle class:

`NSString *languageID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations].firstObject;`

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to fetch Localised language without having trouble to the en-india, en-us etc..

```
 NSString *Ph = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations] objectAtIndex:0];
```

In and After ios9 this code need to take in cosideration

Comment: This does not give current device language.The gives the language that you have given in CFBundleDevelopmentRegion of info.plist

if CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations is true in info.plist then first item of CFBundleLocalizations in info.plist is returned

Answer (score -1):

To know the current language selected within your localizations use

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations]
```

Example:

```
NSString *language = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations] objectAtIndex:0];
```

To get two letter word

```
NSString *language = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations] objectAtIndex:0] substringToIndex:2];
```

Swift:

```
let language = NSBundle.mainBundle().preferredLocalizations.first as NSString
```

Comment: This does not give current device language.The gives the language that you have given in CFBundleDevelopmentRegion of info.plist if CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations is true in info.plist then first item of CFBundleLocalizations in info.plist is returned