# Get system language setting on Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, localization, xamarin, locale

I'm trying to read the *language* setting on iOS. So in the following example I'd like to get "en" or "English", but not "de" or "German":

[image]

I already inspected the whole `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` object from `System.Globalization` and `NSLocale.CurrentLocale` from `MonoTouch.Foundation`. But I only see `de_DE` everywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution based on this [very similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6829448/3419103):

**On iOS** you can get the current language code as the first item of the "preferred languages":

```cs
NSLocale.PreferredLanguages[0]
```

**On Android** the cross-platform solution works just fine:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName
```

To make the language code accessible to the shared code, I'd recommend a public static member of `App.cs`, which is initialized in `OnCreate` or `FinishedLaunching`, respectively.

Comment: iOS solution: this will return a string in the well-known format "xx-YY" with xx being the language designator and YY being the region/country designator. but unlike Microsoft's platforms, this string can assume weird combinations. for example, I had ten iPhone 5s showcased for testing on a fair in Lisbon, and when plugging them in and running in the xamarin debugger, it returned "en-PT".